# RFID user presence detection

Tags: java, rfid

I am making a Java Application and one of the features I want to add is tracking users and reporting their check in time to the application (to be seen by management).
This is a B2B solution that I intend to market to a variety of customers. I am trying to figure out

1. What is the de facto hardware / standard used in RFIDs like what
   kind of hardware should I buy and test/develop on so that I can get
   it to work on the customers' setups.
2. What APIs can I be using for this. Someone referred me to Java-RFID
   API but I am not sure if that is the best option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing and developing I'd have a look at one of the Arduino varietes around. I don't have firsthand experience with Arduino *and* RFID myself, but the platform itself is very easy to get into, especially if you know some C/C++.

Just google Arduino and RFID and you'll get lots of hits.

Cheers,